# Laravel - is it possible to delete a specific job from redis queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For example : When I want to update product I create job for that and I put job into queue. Job is waiting there and it is still not processed, In meantime I need to create new job for update the same product but with different data and now I want to remove old update job from queue and push new one to queue, any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try pop() method? `pop(string $queue = null)`

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea.
On every job dispatch you would set a cache key, this uuid would also be set on the job's properties.

```
$uuid = uuid();
Redis::set("update-product-token-$ID",$uuid);
$data['uuid'] = $uuid;
ProductUpdateJob::dispatch($data);
```

On the first line of the handle function, you check if the redis token matches the job's token. If they don't the job exits gracefully

```
$uuid = Redis::get("update-product-token-$ID",NULL);
if($uuid !== NULL && $uuid !== $this->uuid) return;
//proceed with update here
```

No querying the queue, no guessing, no halting an update mid execution. Elegant stuff. Let me know what you think.